# EF5 Edmx / Code First vs EF6 Edmx / Code First

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first, edmx

I am busy moving fairly complex data model from EF5 to EF6 and in process I noticed some serious performance issues with EF6 (V6.1.0). Whether running complex data model or a very simple one, the performance issues are obvious. The following test is performed on a simple data model containing 5 tables with 5 columns each, queering a single table containing 200 records. Machine is i7 3.4Ghz 8GB RAM, SSD. This is Console application on .Net 4.5.

```
// FIRST RUN
var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
EFTestContext ctx = new EFTestContext();
var data = ctx.Table1.ToList(); // table with 200 records 
ctx.Dispose();
// SECOND RUN
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Completed in {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
sw.Restart();
ctx = new EFTestContext();
data = ctx.Table1.ToList();
ctx.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Completed in {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

Results are as following:

- EF5 Code First – 501ms / 2ms
- EF5 EDMX – 226ms / 2ms
- EF6 Code First – 1346ms / 3ms
- EF6 EDMX – 1189ms / 3m

Generating views on EF6 does improve performance slightly but it still doesn't come close to EF5 start-up and query time.

I must be missing something? Microsoft announced performance enhancements (initialization and query) on EF6? I am aware that there were some performance issues reported on V6.0.0 however reportedly those have been addressed in V6.1.0? Please advise.